# Python - print("abc") giving a syntax error

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

**This print function is giving a syntax error, can't work out why!**

```
if teacher == "no":
    name = input("What is your name?")
    class_code = str(input("What class are you from? 1, 2 or 3?")
    print("Welcome to the Arithmetic Quiz, ",name)
```

**Thanks for any help!**

Comment: Are you using the python 2 interpreter to run python 3 code?

Comment: @BlackBear The `print` shown here is valid in both Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: If this is Python 2, you should be using `raw_input`, not `input`. `input` in Python 3 and `raw_input` in Python 2 both return strings, so the call to `str()` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
class_code = str(input("What class are you from? 1, 2 or 3?")
```

to

```
class_code = str(input("What class are you from? 1, 2 or 3?"))
```